# Grab video frames from all videos in folder, process with openCV, save to own folder?

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I have code like this. I know it's not correct, but I'm new at this and not sure how to fix it. How do I make it so cv2 runs on every video I have in a folder, taking a frame every 3 seconds, and saving the frame images in a new folder within `/data/ --- ex. /data/rise_of_skywalker`?

Thanks

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

def frame_capture(file):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
    try:
        if not os.path.exists('data'):
            os.makedirs('data')
    except OSError:
        print('Error: Creating directory of data')

    currentFrame = 0

    while(True):
      # Capture frame by frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
'''
(((how do I change this block here to get it for every 3 seconds?)))
'''
        if currentFrame == 5:
            name = './data/frame' + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg'
            print ('Creating...' + name)
            cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

      # To stop duplicate images
        currentFrame += 1

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print ("Done!")

for file in os.listdir("/users/x/Desktop/y/videos"):

    if file.endswith(".mp4"):
        path=os.path.join("/users/x/Desktop/y/videos", file))
        frame_capture(path)
```

Comment: It would be simpler with `ffmpeg` https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video

Comment: I think it will be much easier for people to help you if you can cut down the question to the minimum code which is not working as you expect. The process may actually help you find the answer yourself, but will certainly make answering much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is to change the line `if currentFrame == 5:` to `if currentFrame % (3 * fps) == 0:`
And before that line, outside the loop, add `fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)`